# Twill submit function not working with form

Tags: python, forms, web-scraping, web-crawler, twill

I am trying to write a crawler with twill for a page, and it requires me to login. I can fill in the form. But the submit() function of twill does not seem to "click" the button.

```
Form name=fSSUser_Logon (#1)
## ## __Name__________________ __Type___ __ID________ __Value__________________
1     TFORM                    hidden    TFORM        SSUser.Logon 
2     TPAGID                   hidden    TPAGID       SRLpKQyn1yc8 
3     TEVENT                   hidden    TEVENT        
4     TXREFID                  hidden    TXREFID      2 
5     TOVERRIDE                hidden    TOVERRIDE     
6     TDIRTY                   hidden    TDIRTY       1 
7     TWKFL                    hidden    TWKFL         
8     TWKFLI                   hidden    TWKFLI        
9     TFRAME                   hidden    TFRAME        
10    TWKFLL                   hidden    TWKFLL        
11    TWKFLJ                   hidden    TWKFLJ        
12    TREPORT                  hidden    TREPORT       
13    TRELOADCMP               hidden    TRELOADCMP    
14    TRELOADID                hidden    TRELOADID    SRLpKQy1nyc7 
15    TOVERLAY                 hidden    TOVERLAY      
16    RELOGON                  hidden    RELOGON       
17    USERNAME                 text      USERNAME      
18    PASSWORD                 password  PASSWORD      
19    Logon                    button    Logon        Logon
```

showforms() on the page as above.

And the actual code for the button is the following:

```
<input type="button" class="clsButton" id="Logon" name="Logon" tabindex="3" value="Logon" title="Logon">
```

It does not have any formaction I can use.

My code thus far:

```
from twill.commands import *
from twill import get_browser

go("https://trakcarelabwebview.nhls.ac.za/trakcarelab/csp/logon.csp")
showforms()

fv("1", "USERNAME", "xx")
fv("1", "PASSWORD", "xx")
fv("1", "Logon", "Logon")

formaction('Logon','https://trakcarelabwebview.nhls.ac.za/trakcarelab/csp/logon.csp#TRAK_main')
submit()
show()
showforms()
```

Where the frame "TRAK_main" is the frame with the HTML I need.
The last showforms() shows exactly the same forms as before the "login".

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong here?

Your answer lies here:

> twill does not understand javascript.

When a `browser` loads that page, the js on the page executes, and the js assigns an onclick event handler to the Logon button. Then when the Logon button is clicked the event handler function sets the value for one of the hidden form fields.  The server checks for that value in the request, and if the value is absent the login fails, and the server redirects back to the login page.

Because `twill` does not understand js, the value for the hidden form field never gets set, and therefore when twill sends a request to the server the value for the hidden form field is missing in the request.

Websites try all kinds of tricks to keep programs from accessing their pages.

Comment: I have studied the page and not Javascript ie. onClick() event get's triggered. I have managed to log in now with: formaction('Logon','https://trakcarelabwebview.nhls.ac.za/trakcarelab/csp/logon.csp')
submit("Logon") But now the problem is getting into the correct frame that contains the forms I want.

Comment: I managed to write the exact same program with Selenium and it works perfectly. Automated login and automated searches etc. However, obviously I want full automation from a command-line script. Have tried mechanize/scrapy etc. but to no avail. Looks like selenium is the only way.... very annoying.

Comment: @Albert, *I managed to write the exact same program with Selenium and it works perfectly.*  Right.  Selenium pioneered the ability to read the text of an html page and interpret the javascript therein in order to overcome the deficiencies of programs like twill.

Comment: @Albert, *I have studied the page and not Javascript ie. onClick() event get's triggered* -- I've also studied the page, and I can see the button's onclick event in the code, and I can see the token that the js code adds to the form, and I verified that the onclick code does in fact execute by manually clicking the button and checking the name/value pairs that are sent in the request.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. You're completely correct. Looks like this webpage is just too smart for me for now. Thanks for the help!